# How can we calculate swarm storage cost?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, storage, swarm

I am trying to integrate ethereum to another fin-tech app, the basic idea is to store the transaction details on swarm and then pass the hash on ethereum network. I haven't used swarm earlier and I am wondering how to analyze operational cost for the storage?

Answer (score 1):

Zilch! It’s important to note that dapps will only be available via Swarm for 28 days, at which point you’ll have to renew/re-register them. That’s where the up-sell happens, I think.

I’ve read that Swarm will charge for hashes that want to go beyond the set freemium limit.